# CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7: Parse error. Function missing ending ")". End of file reached

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(opencvtest VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

set(OpenCV_DIR C:\Users\Sayar\opencv\build\)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable(opencvtest main.cpp)

target_link_libraries( opencvtest ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

This is my code for CMakeLists.txt. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? Where is the missing ")"?

Comment: `build\)` looks suspicious, not sure if CMake interprets backslash as escape sequence or not

Comment: Paths should be quoted (they may have spaces). Backlashes should be replaced by slashes. Good habit - quote all string values.

Comment: Your bug is:  C:\Users\Sayar\opencv\build\ just like c++ you need to escape the \ character or use a /

Comment: Indeed cmake uses backslash as an escape char. The simplest fix would be to use slashes as path separators. Hardcoding the opencv path on your local machine makes reuse of the project harder though. Imho you're better off passing this info via command line option during configuration (`cmake -D OpenCV_DIR:PATH=C:/Users/Sayar/opencv/build`) or perhaps creating a configuration in `CMakeUserPresets.json`. If you want to keep the info hardcoded  in your project though, at the very least make it a cache variable to allow the user to overwrite the value: `set(OpenCV_DIR ... CACHE PATH "...")`